# Remove log message in active-model-serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

How can I remove this active-model-serializers message from my logs?

`[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi`

Comment: This was answered in a PR request by OP @MSathieu https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/2035/files `ActiveSupport::Notifications.unsubscribe(ActiveModelSerializers::Logging::RENDER_EVENT)` or changing the logger as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41653874/879854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything in AMS configuration to disable logs, however, there are several other ways of achieving this by redefining `ActiveModelSerializers.logger` ([source](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/a032201a91cbca407211bca0392ba881eef1f7ba/lib/active_model_serializers.rb#L19))

in your `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb`:

1) Increase the log level so that nothing will get logged:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.logger.level = Logger::Severity::UNKNOWN
```

or

2) Write AMS log to `/dev/null`

```
ActiveModelSerializers.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new('/dev/null'))
```

Comment: Option (1) breaks logging altogether, and (2) has no effect :(

Answer (score 10):

In your `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb`:

```
require 'active_model_serializers'
ActiveSupport::Notifications.unsubscribe(ActiveModelSerializers::Logging::RENDER_EVENT)
```

This properly unsubscribes you from the rendering event, as opposed to just disabling all logging, etc.
from: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/ab98c4a664f26077e5b3c90ea6bcbe129ec2d0b9/docs/general/logging.md

Answer (score 0):

Since mid-2018, the correct way to do this is in your `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb` is now:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.logger = Logger.new(IO::NULL)
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/commit/be119b8fcbd6851787ef1b4585eceb1aa7e5316d